# Install newer version of bundler with bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler

If I change the version of bundler required in a Gemfile, and then type `bundle`, I get

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (>= 1.10.2) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.9.9)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
Could not find gem 'bundler (>= 1.10.2) ruby in any of the sources
```

Is it possible to ask bundler to install the new version of bundler, rather than typing in `gem install bundler`?

Comment: I'm almost certain you can't make this work, but I can't explain why well enough to give a proper answer.

Comment: If you want an specific version of bundler you can use something like this: `gem install bundler:2.3.11`

Comment: I thought this might be an April Fools joke  but I don't think it is.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[Seems like](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/831#issue/831/comment/532839) bundler can't bundle itself :)

So you have to run `gem install bundler`.

Comment: Nowadays you can just run `bundle update --bundler` and update bundler - https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-update.1.html#OPTIONS

Comment: `bundle update --bundler` seems to update the version referred to in the Gemfile.lock file and not upgrade the actual bundelr gem.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Look no further.

Answer (score 61):

as of v1.14 there is now: `bundle update --bundler`

https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-update.1.html#OPTIONS

Comment: This isn't correct, it only works if you happen to be in a directory that contains a Gemfile.

Comment: Specifically, it updates the `Gemfile.lock` version of bundler to the same as what you use to issue the command. This doesn't update bundler itself.

Answer (score 36):

I think you can just run `gem update bundler`, right?  It worked for me.

Comment: `bundle update --bundler` won't work if you're in a directory with a Gemfile bundled by bundler 2, and you've currently only got bundler 1 installed.

This works everywhere, and should be the correct answer.

Comment: Needed to run `bundle update --bundler` after this one to get my `Gemfile.lock` updated.

Answer (score 16):

As of Bundler 2.3 (in combination with at least RubyGems 3.3), bundler can now fully upgrade itself by running

```
bundle update --bundler
```

This command has existed for a long time, but until now it only updated the version in your `Gemfile.lock` file to be the latest version installed on your system.

Now, it is able to fully upgrade your application to use the latest release of Bundler.

Note that other answers suggesting `gem install bundler` only partially fix the problem, because if you have a `Gemfile.lock` file locked to some old version and it is installed on your system, that version will still be respected even if you install the latest version globally with `gem install bundler`.

`bundle update --bundler` is the right way!

Answer (score 4):

I have found `bundle update --bundler` does not work so well when a default Bundler version is set. This can result in warnings when running `bundle`. I know others above have mentioned using `gem` to install a later version of bundler so expanding off those answers here.

1. **You can run the following but this can present issues as it can break your local gems on your system as ALL of them are updated.**

   ```
   gem update --system
   ```
2. The following method is a much safer way of ensuring Bundler is updated

- Get your gem environment and take note of **INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY**

  ```
  gem environment
  ```
- Then run the following

  ```
  cd <INSTALLATION DIRECTORY>/specifications/default
  rm bundler-<old_default_version>.gemspec
  gem install --default bundler -v <new_default_version>
  ```

3. If you have followed 2 and that still does not work, then run

   ```
   gem install bundler:<new_default_version>
   ```

   to ensure you your local repo is using the correct version

Answer (score 1):

If `gem install bundler` does not upgrade your bundler version, then run `gem install bundler --pre`.

Comment: Note: this will install a prerelease.